# Позиционирование ui календаря

Tags: javascript, ui

Доброго времени суток, есть поле input при клике на кторое пояляется ui календарь, вопрос в следующем, календарь помещается в body, а как сделать так, чтобы он помещался к примеру сразу после input поля???

Comment: @Karalahti, соберите рабочий пример на jsFiddle или хотя бы укажите, о каком именно календаре идет речь и как вы его подключаете.  
Телепатические способности подсказывают мне, что вы говорите о jQuery UI, но их недостаточно для того, чтобы увидеть, как именно вы подключаете календарь к input-полю.  
Плюс вы можете пояснить, почему вам принципиально важно разместить код календаря после input'а?

Comment: Ну собственно вот календарь как и просили http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/Qu5VM/ , сори если что-то было не понятно. Ну а нужно мне это для того что у меня этот календарь находиться в блоке который скролиться, и если нажать на поле и чуть проскролить блок то едит календарь а все потому что он пихаеться в body и позицианируеться отнеосительно верха экрана http://floomby.ru/s1/5WxEr8

Comment: вы можете **повторить** свою проблему ?  дорисуйте разметку/стили здесь http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Qu5VM/2/

Comment: > находиться скролиться пихаеться позицианируеться

http://tsya.ru

Comment: так всеж и так понятно, http://floomby.ru/s1/6WxEBp все остальное я знаю как сделать, мне клавно чтоб он появлялся там где мне нужно, как это сделать я не нашел(((

Comment: Господи, Fike, за комент конечно спасибо, но мы не на руссом языке и вопрос не стоял как "пишуться эти слова" )))

Comment: @Karalahti **пишутся**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем вот вам примерное решение:

```
$(function () {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь',
            'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Вс', 'Пн', 'Вт', 'Ср', 'Чт', 'Пт', 'Сб'],
        buttonImage: '../images/ico_calendar.png',
        beforeShow: moveme
    });
    function moveme(that,obj) {
        $(obj.dpDiv).insertAfter(that);
    }
});
```

вкратце - [перед тем как показать](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) двигаем этот самый datepicker под элемент инпута.

ps: не ожидал что jQueryUI так откровенно лажово задизайнен (очень удивило добавление id к инпуту (типа dp1399365625169) - как у пионеров).

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Qu5VM/3/

Comment: а вот это уже то что мне и нужно, спасибо большое!!!

Comment: если у вас несколько datepicer то я бы рекомендовал вам массивы названий дней недели и месяцев объявить отдельно и потом их использовать в опциях. типа такого: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Qu5VM/4/

Comment: Хм, точно, и код сокротиться))) Спасибо!!!

Comment: https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ef59545dc02685334418ee23a2f30777?s=32&d=identicon&r=g а может вы и на этот вопрос знаете какоенибуть решение http://hashcode.ru/questions/311868/javascript-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-ui